# Add list of results to database in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, html, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

This is my controller:

```
string responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
dynamic jsonData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseString);
var results = new List<Result>();
foreach (var item in jsonData.items)
{
    results.Add(new Result { 
        Title = item.title, 
        Link = item.link, 
        Snippet = item.snippet,
    });
    db.Results.AddRange(results);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
return View(results.ToList());
```

But I get this error:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Result'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Result'. The duplicate key value is (0).
>   The statement has been terminated.

How can I solve that?

Comment: How is the primary key of your object being generated?

Answer (score 2):

```
var results = new List<Result>();
foreach (var item in jsonData.items)
{
    results.Add(new Result { 
        Title = item.title, 
        Link = item.link, 
        Snippet = item.snippet,
    });
    db.Results.AddRange(results);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

On the first line you have initialized new List.

Then on each enumeration of `jsonData.items`:

1. you add new instance of Result type to results list.
2. you add the whole collection to `db.Results DbSet`. Because of `db.Results.AddRange`.

I think that you wanted to have something like this:

```
var results = new List<Result>();
foreach (var item in jsonData.items)
{
    var result = new Result { 
        Title = item.title, 
        Link = item.link, 
        Snippet = item.snippet,
    };
    db.Results.Add(result);
}
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but when i do : db.Results.Add(result) ... i got a error (red line) but when i do db.Results.Add(results) i got nothing but it doesn't working

Comment: Can you share with the code sample, which you have for this moment and give more details about what kind of compilation error do you have?

Answer (score 0):

May be you should include primary key value in `results.Add()` method.
Here you are trying to add values for title, link and snippet.

I believe none of them is primary key.
That's why it takes default value(0) for primary key.

You can check primary key field in your database table and include that as well in `results.Add()` method.

Comment: yes you are right, i didn't include the primary key, but i want it to be auto increment, because i won't controle the results

Comment: Then you can make that table field IDENTITY so that you won't have to add its value manually and it will auto increment.

i.e. ItemId int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp#:~:text=The%20MS%20SQL%20Server%20uses,IDENTITY(10%2C5).